# Shred & Concat XML into single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

what is simple way to produce output concatenated into single column for all Parameter values in sample below, this xml doesn't have an ns in it and I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I try to get this output, below snippet with xml sample produce 3 columns, and I'd like to make 1.

```
100 | Param1
    ,Param22
    ,Param3322
```

XML & code:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<Parameters>    
                       <Parameter>       
                          <Name>Param1</Name>  
                       </Parameter>    
                       <Parameter>    
                          <Name>Param22</Name> 
                       </Parameter>    
                       <Parameter>    
                          <Name>Param3322</Name>    
                       </Parameter> </Parameters>   '

SELECT 100 id
    ,@XML xmlinfo
INTO #t -- drop table #t              --   select * from #t

DECLARE @xml XML = (
        SELECT xmlinfo
        FROM #t
        )

SELECT (
        SELECT ID
        FROM #t
        ) AS ID
    ,X.STockData.query('Name[1]').value('.', 'Varchar(10)') AS 'Parameter'
---CONCAT(X.STockData.query('Name[1]').value('.','Varchar(10)'),X.STockData.query('Name[2]').value('.','Varchar(10)')) AS 'Parameter' 
FROM @xml.nodes('Parameters/Parameter') AS X(StockData)
```

Comment: I have original xml column in  the table #t, I'm not sure how to refer to this column from table, so I put it into back to @xml var.  I also tried to use CONCAT but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use XQuery `for` loop to construct comma-separated value from XML field, for example :

```
SELECT 
    t.ID as ID
    , CAST(t.xmlinfo.query('
                       for $p in Parameters/Parameter
                       return 
                           if ($p is (Parameters/Parameter[last()])[1]) 
                                then string($p/Name[1])
                           else concat($p/Name[1], ", ")
                      ')
        AS VARCHAR(MAX)
      ) as Parameter
FROM MyTable as t
```

**<kbd>[Sqlfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/801d8/1)</kbd>**

The XQuery above simply loop through `Parameter` elements, and return `Name` child element if current `Parameter` is the last `Parameter`, otherwise return `Name` concatenated with comma.

Comment: @MarioTrento please consider [to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer -maybe an upvote as well- to confirm that this is the solution you chose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT (
    SELECT ID
    FROM #t
    ) AS ID
   ,X.STockData.query('Name[1]').value('.', 'Varchar(10)') 
   + ', ' + X.STockData.query('Name[2]').value('.', 'Varchar(10)')
   + ', ' + X.STockData.query('Name[3]').value('.', 'Varchar(10)')
   as parameter
   FROM @xml.nodes('Parameters/Parameter') AS X(StockData)
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks har and vkp,  I go with har solution, as number of params could be different. Tx much